# How to export from query/database table to csv file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export a table to a csv file but I get an error. I tried to troubleshoot but no success.

```vb
Private Sub cmdGenerateExcelFilesPM_Click()

On Error GoTo HandleError

Dim fullPath As String

fullPath = CurrentProject.path

Dim CaseNumber As String

CaseNumber = Forms("Form").Controls("txtCaseNum").Value

Dim query As String
query = "Select * from PromoAPI"

'this line works fine and generate an excel file
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "PromoAPI", 
CurrentProject.path & "\" & CaseNumber & " Promo API" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy"), True

'I need a CVS file - none of the below line works -all of them throw the same error 

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "PromoAPIQuery", CurrentProject.path & "\" & CaseNumber & " Promo API" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy"), True

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "query", CurrentProject.path & "\" & CaseNumber & "Promo API" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy"), True

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "PromoAPI", CurrentProject.path & "\" & CaseNumber & "Promo API" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy"), True

HandleExit:
    Exit Sub

HandleError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume HandleExit

End Sub
```

My query is named PromoAPIQuery:
[image]

The error I get:
[image]

Comment: I know it's just picky but the file type is CSV, not CVS. The `query` variable is of no use. Is SharePoint somehow involved? Review this discussion https://groups.google.com/g/comp.databases.ms-access/c/ZCb2Li_K5kM?pli=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a "bad" error message.

Your issue is you not supplied a file extension (csv) in this case.

Hence, this should work:

```
Dim strF            As String

strF = CurrentProject.path & "\" & _
       CaseNumber & " Promo API" & Format(Now(), " mm dd yyyy") & ".csv"

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "PromoAPIQuery", strF, True
```

so note the "addition" of the ".csv" in above.